# How do I load a configMap in to an environment variable?

Tags: kubernetes

How do I load a configMap into an environment variable?

**Things I've done**

Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-container-environment-variables-using-configmap-data) describes just this scenario, and following it:

I've actually set up my `configMap` through Terraform with this:

```
resource "kubernetes_config_map" "production_database_host" {
  metadata {
    name = "production-database-host"
  }

  data {
    connection_name = "${google_sql_database_instance.master.connection_name}"
  }
}
```

But via Kubernetes, it would look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  connection_name: this_string_is_redacted
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-10-12T05:49:49Z
  name: production-database-host
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "316273"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps/production-database-host
  uid: a1c06423-cde2-11e8-b615-42010a800235
```

(Fetched by running `kubectl get configmap production-database-host -o yaml`)

Now, I also have a working container, in a deployment, where I added an environment variable like so:

```
env:
 - name: INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME
   valueFrom:
     configMapKeyRef:
       name: production-database-host
       key: connection_name
```

However, applying this config gives me:

```
$ kubectl apply -f .

error: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 39: did not find expected key
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why won't this simply load `this_string_is_redacted` into the `INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME` environment variable?

**Edit:** All the source for my infrastructure is in this [repo](https://github.com/amingilani/infrastructure). The Terraform files are applied first, they create the Kubnernetes cluster and add the configMap. Then I apply the Kubernetes config.

Comment: Can you paste entire yaml that you used. Something wrong in yaml? whether it could be format issue, wrong api-version for sections that you defined in yaml or syntax errors.

Comment: Looking forward for the manifest yaml file of your deployment.

Comment: Looks like formatting issues, which file is the one you are applying and giving the error specifically?

Comment: @Veerendra I can do one better, I've pasted a link to the repo with entire codebase.

Comment: @mk_sta done, I've added all the source files.

Comment: @Rico I for Kubernetes, I'm applying this file: https://github.com/amingilani/infrastructure/blob/master/kubernetes/website.yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a formatting issue, unfortunately the block:

```
env:
 - name: INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME
   valueFrom:
     configMapKeyRef:
       name: production-database-host
       key: connection_name
```

Was indented one space more than I should have been. Everything else works fine.