# Is there a different way to include .conf file in my pod?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm making use of a conf file in my pod which is necessary for my application.
Right now I'm adding this conf file directly to my Docker image with

```
COPY ./example.conf  /etc/example.conf
```

This is the contents of my conf file

```
[example]
url = url
username = username
password = password
```

I want to be able to give the url dynamically via helm (or some other way), so the docker image method is not suitable. How do I approach this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `volume` and `volumeMount` to refactor your project.

[k8s volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/)

[configMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/)

Note:

- You can create a ConfigMap before you can use it.
- A container using a ConfigMap as a subPath volume mount will not receive ConfigMap updates.
- Text data is exposed as files using the UTF-8 character encoding. For other character encodings, use binaryData.

e.g.

configmap.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-conf
data:
  example.conf: |
    url = url
    username = username
    password = password
```

pod.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test
      image: busybox:1.28
      volumeMounts:
        - name: conf
          mountPath: /etc/
  volumes:
    - name: conf
      configMap:
        name: test-conf
```

Comment: I do not have a pod.yaml file, I just have a deployment.yaml file. So what do I do in that case ?

Comment: Not much difference. Have a look at the example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71058264/1722326
Should give you an idea.

Comment: Thank you so much both of you! I could successfully add the conf file!